Google Maps Compose - How to set Marker to center of screen but map can be draggable?
I want to set the marker to center of the map view, so when user drag the map view it change the map position, but marker should be in center of the screen, so we can get the new latitude and longitude of the marker position, similar to Uber/Ola/Zomato? I have tried to set marker as draggable but it makes marker only draggable but I want screen only draggable, How can I achieve this? Thanks in Advance!
I have attach the code below:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
fun MapScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    val (addressQuery, setAddressQuery) = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var initialLocation = remember { mutableStateOf(LatLng(0.132828, 100.804833)) }
    val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
        position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(initialLocation.value, 5f)
    }
    val locationPermission = rememberMultiplePermissionsState(
        listOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
    )
    var uiSettings = MapUiSettings(
        compassEnabled = true,
        rotationGesturesEnabled = true,
        scrollGesturesEnabled = true,
        tiltGesturesEnabled = false,
        zoomControlsEnabled = false,
        zoomGesturesEnabled = true,
        mapToolbarEnabled = false,
        myLocationButtonEnabled = false,
        scrollGesturesEnabledDuringRotateOrZoom = true,
        indoorLevelPickerEnabled = true
    )
    var mapProperties = MapProperties(
        maxZoomPreference = 15f,
        minZoomPreference = 1f,
        isTrafficEnabled = false,
        mapType = MapType.NORMAL,
        isMyLocationEnabled = locationPermission.allPermissionsGranted,
    )
    var mapColorScheme = remember { mutableStateOf(ComposeMapColorScheme.FOLLOW_SYSTEM) }
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.pinnedScrollBehavior(rememberTopAppBarState())
    var marker = remember {  MarkerState(position = initialLocation.value) }
    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = {
                    if (locationPermission.allPermissionsGranted) {
                        cameraPositionState.position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(initialLocation.value, 15f)
                    } else {
                        locationPermission.launchMultiplePermissionRequest()
                    }
                },
                contentColor = if (locationPermission.allPermissionsGranted) LogoBlue else Gray
            ) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_gps),
                    contentDescription = "Calibrate to current location",
                    tint = LogoBlue
                )
            }
        },
        topBar = {
            CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_pocket_small),
                        contentDescription = null
                    )
                }, colors = TopAppBarDefaults.centerAlignedTopAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                    titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                ),
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        navController.navigateUp()
                    }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.AutoMirrored.Filled.ArrowBack,
                            contentDescription = "back arrow",
                            tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary
                        )
                    }
                },
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
            )
        }
    ) { paddingValues ->
        if (locationPermission.allPermissionsGranted) {
            LocationFetcher { location, string ->
                location?.let {
                    initialLocation.value = LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude)
                    cameraPositionState.position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude), 15f)
                }
            }
        }
        Box(Modifier.padding(top = paddingValues.calculateTopPadding())) {
            GoogleMap(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
                mapColorScheme = mapColorScheme.value,
                uiSettings = uiSettings,
                properties = mapProperties,
            ) {
                MarkerComposable(
                    state = marker,
                    title = "Current Location",
                    content = {
                        Text("Hello World")
                    }
                )
            }
            Column(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                CustomSearchView(
                    addressQuery,
                    onValueChange = {
                        println(it)
                        setAddressQuery(it)
                    }) {
                    addressList()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Off the cuff: render the marker independent of the map, centered over the map.

So then we need to get the latitude and longitude based on center position of the screen? @CommonsWare

Yes, you would the map details to determine the latitude and longitude at the map's center.

Is there any Blog or Minimum reproducible code available to achieve this functionality using Google Maps Compose library? @CommonsWare
